# page transition for app using jquery mobile and phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I'm building an app in html/css/javascript and using phonegap to build.

So, I first wanted to have to simple page to page navigation. I tryed this:

index:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="body">
    <div id="container" data-role="page">
        <a rel="external" data-role="button" href="test.html" data-transition="slide">click me</a>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="body">
    <div id="container" data-role="page">
        New page!
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Result: when I click on the button the test.html page loads very slow and the data-transition="slide" seems to be ignored.

I found an article about dynamic page loading: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/94e7fded-7162-445e-8ceb-97a2140866a9/entry/dynamic_page_loading_for_phonegap1?lang=en

Which I really don't get. Aren't the HTML files stored locally? So why do a XMLHtppRequest?

My question is: How do I get a good page transition (fast and with effects)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove `rel="external"` from your `<a>` link.

The attribute `rel="external"` disables the Ajax navigation, skipping the transition effect, and refreshes your page `test.html`.

Try your code after removing it.

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="body">
    <div id="container" data-role="page">

        <!-- REMOVE THE ATTRIBUTE REL="EXTERNAL" FROM THE LINK -->
        <a data-role="button" href="test.html" data-transition="slide">click me</a>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

`test.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="body">
    <div id="container" data-role="page">
        New page!
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Let me know about your results.

Comment: I get: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///<my path>/test.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Error is gone. But still no transition

Comment: I build it on Phonegap. It's still very slow and no page transition. Using Galaxy Nexus 4.1

Comment: Could you open your file `cordova.xml` and check that you have the line `<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> ` ? Also, could you confirm that both your html files `index.html` and `test.html` are in your `assets/www` folder?

Comment: I didnt have that file yet. So I made it, it's called config.xml now btw. The transition is showing now! But it's still very very slow.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://outof.me/fixing-flickers-jumps-of-jquery-mobile-transitions-in-phonegap-apps/) solution by Piotr Walczyszyn. Highly recommended for anyone using Jquery mobile and Phonegap together.